# What was this live filtered table implemented with?

Tags: user-interface, web, web-controls

I was just browsing http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/

I like the way that the table at the bottom of the page works, with its various live filtering & sort options. Particularly its speed, fluidity & function.

Does anyone know how this would have been implemented (I'm talking specifically, I have a good understanding of the generalized process, and am interested in the specific technology if it already exists as a particular type of control in/on a particular platform)?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the page source it looks like the DataTables plug in for jquery [see here](http://www.datatables.net/)